# Vertical line to ngx-charts

Tags: css, angular, typescript, ngx-charts

How i can to add two vertical lines to stacked horizontal bar? 
This is my [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/swimlane-stacked-horizontal-bar-chart-nufj9z?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

I need to add something similar to red lines over stacked bar:

[i looking make this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i8JkD.png)

if not possible, what's your recommendation for make this work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

U can not do it with ngx-charts. It is not a kind of line chart. It is a bullet chart. I suggest u to use highchart. https://www.highcharts.com/demo/bullet-graph

https://github.com/cebor/angular-highcharts

https://github.com/cebor/angular-highcharts/issues/159

I  created  one example demo for u

https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-angular-demo-v3pgaa